# How to set link to check checkbox with variable name,id,value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a long list of checkboxes each with a link next to it. Something like:

```
<form name="checkboxlist" action="..." >
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="pageCB" value="1"/>
    <a id="1" href="#" onclick="sub(id)>click here</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="pageCB" value="2"/>
    <a id="2" href="#" onclick="sub(id)>click here</a>
    ...
    ...
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I am currently trying to use:

```
<script>
    function sub(id){
        $("input:checkbox[value=id]").attr("checked", true);
        document.checkboxlist.submit(); 
    }
</script>
```

But this obviously does not read the variable id and I would really like to avoid making if statements for each id as there are several hundred of them.  Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Are you able to modify the html? It is not valid to have multiple, identical id's on a page. I would suggest using <label> and adding an onlick handler to the checkboxes

Comment: If you know the id, it can't be more simple than $("#" + id).attr("checked", true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** I see you're also using duplicate IDs. This is invalid, and things will not work properly when selecting by ID.

---

Numeric IDs are invalid in HTML4.

Anyway, change this:

```
$("input:checkbox[value=id]")
```

to this:

```
$("input:checkbox[value='" + id + "']")
```

This concatenates the value of `id` into the selector string, and I also added quotation marks around the attribute selector value since they're required by the docs.

And change your inline handlers to this:

```
<a id="2" href="#" onclick="sub(this.id)>click here</a>
```

...because `this` is a reference to the element clicked, so `this.id` is a reference to its ID attribute.

Comment: yep, I'm an idiot. I had tried concatenating it but it didn't work without the quotes around the attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use a link you should use a `<label>` tag.

That's what it's made for.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" id="mybox">
<label for="mybox">Click this box</label>
```

This works for all form fields and is way better than having to build JS to do something that already exists.

Comment: Agreed, but this doesn't help trigger the submit on checkbox change

Comment: Ahh, but you could easily attached that one event to all labels in the form, but that wouldn't be a very good user experience.

Comment: Indeed. Auto-submitting the form on click does seem a bit odd. Oh vell... OP knows what he wants I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to support selecting checkboxes by clicking on an associated element, and to submit the form on click. I would suggest a) Use a `<label>` element in place of `<a>` as they can be associated with inputs by id and b) don't use numeric, duplicate `id` attributes.

```
<form name="checkboxlist" action="#">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a" name="pageCB" value="1"/>
    <label for="a">Click here</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="b" name="pageCB" value="2"/>
    <label for="b">Click here</label>
</form>    

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
            $(this).parent('form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```